# save data into google SreadSheet with HTML service

Tags: html, google-sheets

I'm working with HTML service.

I create a form submit in HTML service and I want to save the data into google spreadSheet.

Someone can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in a couple of ways, 1) server-side using the Zend Gdata framework and 2) client side using a spreadsheet app script.

**Client Side**

[Mashe Hawksey wrote a post in his blog here](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2011/10/google-spreadsheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-form-postget-submit-method/) about how to do this purely on the client side using a basic HTML form that posts the data to a google apps macro script and targets a hidden iframe to get around the cross-domain issue.

- [Here is the example form from the above tutorial.](http://mashe.hawksey.info/examlpes/insert-eg.html)
- [Here is the spreadsheet of the data being collected into.](https://docs.google.com/a/srwa.co.uk/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqGkLMU9sHmLdDlXcU52LWZHZUdfallfbE10T2tMLWc&hl=en_GB#gid=1)

I started off using the above method, which does work, but didn't have all the functionalities I need to authenticate users.

**Server Side**

Using the [Zend GData Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html) it has much wider scope of functions, but does require a little bit of PHP knowledge.

This is what I now use and it has been a life saver with creating Google apps and using user provisioning with our Google domain.

I hope the above helps.